# MPMoviePlayerController disappears after switching Views

Tags: ipad, media, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a 3 Movie players added to three different views. When I switch randomly between the views when the movie is only played for a few seconds, out of the blue the player vanishes on all subsequent views.

I am not releasing my view any where so, I cannot figure out why my player disappears

here is the code I use in my View id Load method along with the notification method.

```
movieUrl =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Old Spice-Ad" ofType:@"mp4"];

player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieUrl]];

player.view.frame =CGRectMake(38,380,211,122);

[self.view addSubview:player.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player] ;



- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:theMovie];
    [theMovie stop];
    [theMovie release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MPMoviePlayerController class reference:

Note: Although you may create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time may play its movie.